# Data value not recognised in query mysql

Tags: mysql

I have this query that gets data from database first orders it by date then orders it by date and urgjenc_kod, but because i have added DATE(t.data) the date is not recognised this is the query.

```
SELECT list.* from(SELECT t.`id_ticket`,ts.`status_pershkrim`,DATE(t.`data`),
  t.`klient_emer`, t.`email`, t.`nr_tel`, nu.`urgjence_pershkrim`, 
  tp.`problematika_pershkrim`, t.`detaje`, t.`Stafi`,t.updated,u.emer as caktuar,
  t.status_id,t.urgjence_id,t.Stafi_krijues,t.urgjence_kod
FROM ticket t
LEFT JOIN  user u on u.id=t.drejtuar
LEFT JOIN tipi_problematikes tp ON t.tipi_problematikes = tp.problematika_id
LEFT JOIN nivel_urgjence nu on t.urgjence_id=nu.urgjence_id
LEFT JOIN ticket_status ts on t.status_id=ts.status_id
LEFT JOIN nivel_urgjence uk on t.urgjence_kod = uk.urgjence_kod
Where vis=1
ORDER BY t.data DESC LIMIT 100) as list order by list.data desc, list.urgjence_kod asc
```

the **list.data** isnt recognised and throws error `Warning: mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given`

Comment: Your PHP usage is incorrect and because of that not as useful. Use proper error reporting with mysqli and it will tell you the mysql error. The `Warning:` is a PHP warning because your query returned FALSE and false can't be fetched. MySQLi would return mysql error code and error message. See https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/error_reporting

Comment: @user3783243 i didnt post php code i posted query, and as you can see someone gave correct answer.

Comment: `Warning: mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given` is a PHP warning. You should have received a mysql error though. `bool given` is not useful for debugging.

Comment: @user3783243 yet the error was in the query not in the php code, the error was more specific in the mysql saying that it didnt recognise the list.data this is why the only answer given by Stu solved my problem.

Comment: Yes, but you should be getting more detailed errors in PHP. If you use the error reporting functions from mysqli it will tell you the issue as well. Per previous link, `Unfortunately, this error message tells you nothing of the actual problem. It just bluntly says that your query failed, and nothing else.

It happens because by default mysqli is configured to remain silent if a query returned an error. So you can tell that's an extremely inconvenient behavior.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a column *alias*

```
..., DATE(t.`data`) as `data`,...
```